# SQL selecting the oldest enrollment dates and joining tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

[image][image]I need to get the 100 students with the oldest enrollment date from the table students and then join it with the table grades:
I am using this statement:

```
 Select *
 from (select top (100) s.*
  from students s
 ) s inner join
 grades g
 on s.PERSON_ID = g.PERSON_ID
 order by ENROLL_DATE ASC
```

But the result i am getting is wrong. It skips a lot of students and shows some students that has a newer enrollment date than the ones that are skipped. I don't why it does this, is the statement I am using wrong for this? The system i am using is MS SQL. Hope someone can help me.

Comment: You need to order by enroll_date inside the select with the top. Your current way is select any 100 students randomly and then ordering.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the query is that the order by is done after the join between the two tables. You need to add the order by in the interim table s made from the student table before making the join.

Code will look something like this:

```
Select * from 
 (select top (100) s.*
  from students s
  order by ENROLL_DATE ASC
 ) s inner join
 grades g
 on s.PERSON_ID = g.PERSON_ID
```

Comment: When do this i get a result of "No rows" :/

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first enrolled 100 students, you need to order inside the sub-query.  Otherwise you just pick 100 students at random.

Then, if some of those students might not have any grades, you need to use a `LEFT JOIN` in the outer query.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT TOP(100) *
    FROM students
ORDER BY enroll_date ASC
)
  s
LEFT JOIN
  grades g
    ON s.PERSON_ID = g.PERSON_ID
```

Comment: The result comes out with blank rows :(

Comment: @DewanHansen : What is a "blank row"?  Add something to your question to demonstrate and explain.

Comment: I have added a picture of it in my question

Comment: @DewanHansen : Run just the sub-query for me and show what that returns?  *(Just the top 100 students, no join on grades...)*

Comment: A picture of it is in my question now :)

Comment: @DewanHansen - No idea then.  It looks like SQLKomando is flaking out to me.  Try my answer with `SELECT s.*` instead of `SELECT *` at the start.

Comment: Still empty rows :/ but thank you for your time!